# Comparing timestamps in Android/Firebase from 2 different users

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Java and Android and I am making a train app for my college project. The situation is that only 1 seat is available in the train and number of people who want to book that seat is 2(could be more as well). I want my app to book the seat for that person who selected that seat first in their android app and display "seat cannot be booked" to the other person.How do I use timestamp in this case to compare input time from two different devices or users? Also, if both the users somehow selected that seat at the same time, I want the app to book the seat for that person who appears first in the database that I have created in the Firebase (I have made a database for trains and users). How do I do this?

Comment: Either each Android app will have to send across timezone information, or each app will have to send a timestamp in a common timezone, e.g. UTC.

Comment: if you are use long data type for time, then its easy to compare both time. just get values in long change it in your required format. compare both times even a fraction of millisecond difference will be noted

Comment: Relying on the device time would not be my first option here since users can easily cheat with it. Record the time when the request hits the server and use that time for comparison.

Comment: I suggest that you don’t need to compare timestamps. You need [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions). In a transaction check to see if the seat is already booked. If it isn’t, book it to the person wanting to book it. The transaction will make sure that only one can book it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of, is to assign to each seat object in your train, an `available` property of type boolean with the default value of `true`. Once an user is booking that seat, turn the value of this property to `false` and assign the seat to that user. Even if the second user is trying to book that seat after a few milliseconds, that seat won't be available anymore. So there is no need to compare two timestamps in this case.

Comment: This timestamp thing is the last feature/part of my project and I have not yet reached that part.I will revert back once I try your suggestion.Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Thanks for the solution... To the person who is reading this, we used his available suggestion, but instead of assigning that property to the seats, we used an available child in database of trains. It actually helped us in our case... To Alex Mano, thanks for the tip man. My project was the best one :)